# How can I write test code for abort method with flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I'm trying to write test code for testing abort method but I could not find solution with it. How can I access the error message coming from werkzeug ? Would anyone please tell me tips to deal with this issue ?

.py code written by flask

```
def check_access_token(func):
　　@wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
　　　　　...
        ...
            if not rows_all:
                abort(401, {"error_message": "access token is ineffective."})
             ...
             ...
             ...
```

test code with pytest

```
with app.test_request_context(path, method="POST", headers=headers, data=payload) as req:
        def mock():
            return jsonify(["dummy"]), 200
        func = check_access_token(mock)
        import pdb;
        pdb.set_trace()
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

debug result

```
(Pdb) p func(req.request)
[]
*** werkzeug.exceptions.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: {'error_message': 'access token is ineffective.'}
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Why dont u use `unittest` library? u can send a `get` request using `requests` library and then assert the response

Comment: I use pytest and this code is just a small part of the entire complicated code. There are several reasons that I don't use unittest. So I need solution for the above question for now.Or you mean that I can get the error_message if I use requests library ? Would you please tell me more about what you think about ?

Comment: u are returning a json for error message, u can use `json.load(requests.get(url).text)` as the response, u can use `requests.get(url).status_code` as the status code and ..., there is a lot of great things u can do using `requests` itself

Comment: Sorry that I'm confused now. I know this way of using requests but how is it connected with the issue that I have ? I mean how is it related to werkzeug ?

Comment: Its not, I just suggested the `requests` cause writing a test like this is easier using that